# Responsive Thumbnail Grid with Images Centered Vertically and Horizontally in Square 1:1 Container

Tags: css, thumbnails, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive thumbnail grid with the following requirements:

- Thumbnails expand and contract responsively
- Individual thumbnail image containers are square 1:1 aspect ratio
- Individual thumbnail images can vary in aspect ratio but are centered horizontally and vertically within the square thumbnail container

You can see the non-responsive version at my site http://www.artrogue.com/collections/all. Again, this works because I have defined the height and width of 1:1 square container.

With responsive we can't define the height of the square container because the width changes. The height is a moving target.

I'm not sure if this can be done with CSS but I don't mind using some jQuery or JavaScript.